# Get all dictionary values for certain keys (in an array)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get all the values of keys that are only in an array after filtering

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Calendar"]) {
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
        self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[allsearchDictKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
    }
}
```

How can I get an array, that has the values for the keys in `self.searchResults` array only, with the same indexPaths as their counterpart?

This is being passed into my `UISearchResults` updating `tableView`, so I would like this to occur prior to the update so I don't have to do much in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I know I can enumerate through them, and add those objects to another array, but my question is can I bypass that and just simply directly add them to an array?

Example:

```
self.searchResultsValuesArray = [searchDict valuesForKeys:self.searchResults];
```

I know there is no `valuesForKeys` but it's there for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NSDictionaryMethod` [`objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:)

```
self.searchResultsValuesArray = [searchDict objectsForKeys:self.searchResults notFoundMarker:@""];
```

Comment: thank you. I actually tried that, but go an error since I had nil and was using nil for a non nil object. I guess simply putting `@""` makes it work great. thanks

Comment: Yes, you can store `nil` in an `NSArray`.  You could use `[NSNull null]` if you don't want to use an empty string

Comment: That should be *can't* store `nil`

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I just learned something. That applies to all instances of most 'non nullable' circumstances?

Comment: Neither dictionaries nor arrays can store nil just as they can't store an int because it isn't an object.  `[NSNull null]` is a special singleton object.  As it is a singleton the `null` class method always returns the same instance ensuring that equality comparisons will work correctly.